# Pinch zoom on img tag in html + android

Tags: android, pinchzoom

i have a html content in android like the following, which is rendered through webview:

```
<p>blahblah</p><img src="http://blah.com/abc/bhu.png"><div>abcxyz</div><img src="http://blah.com/xyz/mno.png">
```

How can i implement pinch zoom functionality when `img` tags in the above html are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Use this for enable zoom in webview

```
mWebview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
```

Use this for enable zoom buttons